# Where can I use & and == when comparing constants? What is the difference?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

i want to know whats diffrence between :

`file.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`

and :

`file.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`

when i use the first one i get more files.

`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` is a File Attribute Constants and `file.dwFileAttributes` is a `WIN32_FIND_DATA` structure member in windows API.

Comment: The first checks whether a specific bit is set in `dwFileAttributes`, the other checks whether that specific bit is set and no other bit.

Comment: Do you know what bits are, in binary numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is simple:

- When the variable can hold exactly one value, you test with the equality operator, `==`.
- When the variable can hold zero, one or more flags, you test for the presence of the flag with the bitwise and operator, `&`.

In the case of `dwFileAttributes`, the documentation says:

> The file attributes of a file. For possible values and their descriptions, see ...

The use of the plural indicates that the second of my bullet points applies.

Comment: Unless you are guaranteed that the flags are each a single, distinct bit, the correct test is `if ((value & flag) == flag)`, and if the value is encoded as a group of bitfields, then `if ((value & mask) == flag)` where `mask` matches the entire field.  Since we're discussing Win32 APIs, a canonical example where the shortcut of `if (value & flag)` is incorrect would be window styles.  A specific example is that `if (style & WS_CAPTION)` fails to distinguish whether the window has a title bar.

Answer (score 2):

`&` is bitwise *and* operation, while `==` is an actual comparison.

**Bitwise AND**

```
#define FLAG_1 1
#define FLAG_2 2
#define FLAG_3 4
#define FLAG_4 8

/* Check if FLAG_2 or FLAG_3 is enabled in flags */
if ((flags & FLAG_2) || (flags & FLAG_3)) {
    ...
}
```

The are plenty of resources about bitwise AND and other fundamental bit operations. [Wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).

**Regular comparison**

```
#define FLAG_1 1
#define FLAG_2 2
#define FLAG_3 4
#define FLAG_4 8

/* Check if flags is *equal* to FLAG_2 value */
if (flags == FLAG_2) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `&` is not any kind of comparison. It yields an integer value; using it as a condition will test that value is zero or non-zero.

Comment: Thanks, updated. I was in preparation of the longer, more descriptive answer. I guess I will make it even nicer, so don't judge hard so fast.

Answer (score 1):

`file.dwFileAttributes` is an integer type that is being used as flags. Each bit represents a flag (0 or 1 for set or not set)

`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` is an integer with a single bit set. (that bit represents whether the file is a directory)

`file.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` returns non-zero if `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` flag is set.

`file.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` returns true if the only flag that is set is `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`.

Comment: In case this is not clear to OP: in C, integer value 0 means false, any other integer means true. That's why using result of & operator directly in condition works. Also, actually == gives an integer too, 0 or 1.